# UITapGestureRecognizer working on UIImageView but not on UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableViewCell` class named `CommentsTableViewCell` which among other things includes a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.

Code I'm using:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CommentsTableViewCell.showUserViewController))
nameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
avatarRoundImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
nameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
avatarRoundImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

As you can understand I have a function which shows another `UIViewController` whenever the `UIImageView` or the `UILabel` is tapped.

What buffles me is that the `tapGesture` works correctly on the `UIImageView` but not on the `UILabel`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need different gesture for all control

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CommentsTableViewCell.showUserViewController))
avatarRoundImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
avatarRoundImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

let tapGesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CommentsTableViewCell.showUserViewController))
nameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
nameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture2)
```

Comment: I had a different issue, but seeing the userInteractionEnabled flag in your answer helped me to solve it, thanks!  By the way, it's changed to isUserInteractionEnabled now.

Comment: @dcp keep it up.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create two `UITapGestureRecognizer` object because `UITapGestureRecognizer` works with single `UI` element object. So create second `TapGestureRecognizer` and assign one to `UILabel` and one to `UIImageView`.

From `UIGestureRecognizer` documentation.

> A gesture recognizer operates on touches hit-tested to a specific view and all of that view’s subviews. It thus must be associated with that view. To make that association you must call the UIView method `addGestureRecognizer(_:)`. A gesture recognizer doesn’t participate in the view’s responder chain.