# Tap gesture recognizer doesn't work on imageview that's on top of cell because of prepareforsegue?

Tags: ios, swift, cell, gesture, tap

Because I have a segue linked to the cell to pass image from the cell to another view, tap doesn't work on the imageview that's on top of the cell.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "photoview" {
    let vc = segue.destination as! PhotoViewController
    let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) {
        vc.mainURL = self.images[indexPath.row].rawURL
    }
    }
}


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    cellImageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    photographerImageView = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView
    photographerLabel = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UILabel
    photographerLabel.text = images[indexPath.row].photographerName
    photographerImageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
   /*     var tapImage = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        photographerImageView = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView
        tapImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CollectionViewController.openPhotographerPortfolio))
        tapImage.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        photographerImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        photographerImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapImage) */
    addDropshadow(toView: photographerImageView)
    addDropshadow(toView: photographerLabel)
    collectionView.bringSubview(toFront: photographerImageView)
    photographerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = photographerImageView.frame.width / 2
    photographerImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    photographerImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    photographerImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    photographerImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapImage)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `tapImage`?

Comment: In the collectionview controller class.

Comment: Compare with this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/40483099/6433023

Comment: @NiravD I don't want to add a tap gesture to the label, only to the image view, however it does not work.

Comment: What i'm saying you need to create tapGesture instance for every cell of table.Not just one. So create one tapGesture instance in `cellForItemAt` and add it to the imageView.

Comment: Doesn't work. Can you give an example, maybe I'm missing something. sorry :(

Comment: Edit your question with you have tried.

Comment: @NiravD never mind it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: when you click on image is it moving your screen to `PhotoViewController`?

Comment: @NiravD It worked. Thank you :D

Comment: @NiravD actually it only displays one url, not the one at indexpath :/

Comment: when you click on image is it moving your screen to PhotoViewController?

Comment: Not now, it's opening the url, however it's not correct. I have it so it opens the user's portfolio but it doens't open the one at indexpath.

Comment: Doesn't get you if you just want to pass the image URL then what is the need of tapGesture you can even use didSelectItem method too.