# How directly initialize View in PanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

In my `ViewController` I have three views.
I want to add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in this.

Below is my code...

```
var circlePanGesture  = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
var sqaurePanGesture  = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
var trianglePanGesture  = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

var destination = [UIView]()

@IBOutlet weak var circle_source: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var square_source: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var triangle_source: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    panGestureConfiguration()
}

func UIConfiguration() {
    circle_source.layer.cornerRadius = circle_source.frame.size.width/2
    circle_source.clipsToBounds = true        
}

func panGestureConfiguration() {
    circlePanGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(draggedSourceView(_:)))
    circle_source.addGestureRecognizer(circlePanGesture)

    sqaurePanGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(draggedSourceView(_:)))
    square_source.addGestureRecognizer(sqaurePanGesture)

    trianglePanGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(draggedSourceView(_:)))
    triangle_source.addGestureRecognizer(trianglePanGesture)

}
```

In this ViewController's `panGestureConfiguration` function I want to use only one `UIPanGestureRecognizer` object instead of three.  So how to do it?

Please give me any solution for this.

Comment: No thats not possible for each view you need to have separate `UIPanGestureRecognizer` object

Comment: I want to pass two views to one UIPanGestureRecognizer object

Comment: Thats not possible check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483099/uitapgesturerecognizer-working-on-uiimageview-but-not-on-uilabel/) for more detail

Comment: actually you don't pass VCs to 'UIPanGestureRecognizer' instead of that you should set 'gestureRecognizer' to VCs, then for each view you should do that.

Comment: I am not undestanding...please tell me in detail.

Comment: @VikasDhasal You can't set one gesture to multiple views, if you try to set one gesture to multiple views then the view to which you'll set the gesture in last will have effect of it and gestures from other views will get removed.

Comment: Can I directly initialize views in addGestureRecognizer()

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567684/5622566 for more detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you attach a UIGestureRecognizer to multiple views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views)

Comment: And here you can find a workaround if you wan this to reduce number of lines in code https://stackoverflow.com/a/40405568/5622566